# Is OOP possible using discord.py without cogs?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

These last few days, I've been trying to adapt the structure of a discord bot written in discord.py to a more OOP one (because having functions lying around isn't ideal).

But I have found way more problems that I could have ever expected. The thing is that I want to encapsulate all my commands into a **single** class, but I don't know what decorators to use and how and which classes I must inherit.

What I've achieved so far is code like the snippet down below. It runs, but at the moment of executing a command it throws errors like

> discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandNotFound: Command "status" is not found

I'm using Python 3.6.

```
from discord.ext import commands


class MyBot(commands.Bot):

    def __init__(self, command_prefix, self_bot):
        commands.Bot.__init__(self, command_prefix=command_prefix, self_bot=self_bot)
        self.message1 = "[INFO]: Bot now online"
        self.message2 = "Bot still online {}"

    async def on_ready(self):
        print(self.message1)

    @commands.command(name="status", pass_context=True)
    async def status(self, ctx):
        print(ctx)
        await ctx.channel.send(self.message2 + ctx.author)


bot = MyBot(command_prefix="!", self_bot=False)
bot.run("token")
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To register the command you should use `self.add_command(setup)`, but you can't have the `self` argument in the `setup` method, so you could do something like this:

```py
from discord.ext import commands
    
class MyBot(commands.Bot):
    
    def __init__(self, command_prefix, self_bot):
        commands.Bot.__init__(self, command_prefix=command_prefix, self_bot=self_bot)
        self.message1 = "[INFO]: Bot now online"
        self.message2 = "Bot still online"
        self.add_commands()
    
    async def on_ready(self):
        print(self.message1)
    
    def add_commands(self):
        @self.command(name="status", pass_context=True)
        async def status(ctx):
            print(ctx)
            await ctx.channel.send(self.message2, ctx.author.name)
        
    
bot = MyBot(command_prefix="!", self_bot=False)
bot.run("token")
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, It really helped me!. However, I think the name of the method shouldn't be "add_commands" since there is already a method called "add_command" in the Bot class (that got me confused for 5 minutes :P).

Comment: I'm glad it helped!

Comment: If anyone finds this and is getting a `discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandRegistrationError: The command status is already an existing command or alias.` or `discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: TypeError: send() takes from 1 to 2 positional arguments but 3 were given` errors, try removing `self.add_command(status)` and updating the send line to `await ctx.channel.send(f'{self.message2}, {ctx.author.name}')` That got it working for me.

Comment: why would you need a `name="status"` when the command is called `status`?

Comment: This answer helped but, commands don't start. It doesn't give any error, and I even added `self.process_command(message)` in `on_message(message)` method

Answer (score 3):

I have the same problem and found this work-around today. But I found a similar solution without using a method to add the commands:

```
from discord.ext import commands

class DiscordBot(commands.Bot):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(command_prefix="!")

        @self.command(name='test')
        async def custom_command(ctx):
            print("Hello world !")

    async def on_ready(self):
        print(f"Bot {self.user.display_name} is connected to server.")

bot = DiscordBot()
bot.run("token")
```