# How can I run a command from another command?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to write a Discord bot, where if I run a certain command, a part of the program will run, but the other part won't.

For example: In my case, when they type in `"?m"`, they will get a message saying `"xy"`, but then for 90 seconds, they won't be able to call that command again. If they do call it in this 90 second period, another command called `"?x"` will run.

Can someone help me out?

Comment: Try calling the `?x` command's function (with `await`), passing the same `Context`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it using `bot.invoke()` method:

```py
@bot.command()
async def x(ctx):
    pass  # whatever here


@bot.command()
async def m(ctx):
    if something:
        ctx.command = bot.get_command("x")
        await bot.invoke(ctx)  # invoke a command called x
```

Answer (score 0):

With Python's [`time`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html) module, you can check how long it's been since the command was last successfully called. [`time.time()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.time) returns the current time (expressed as a number of seconds since January 1st, 1970).

Calling one command from within another can be as simple as calling it with `await`, like any other coroutine, and passing the same context to it.

```
import time
from discord.ext.commands import Bot
from tokens import TOKEN

bot = Bot(command_prefix='?')
# Set the initial time as 0 (effectly 1970) so it was definitely long
# ago for the command to now be called.
last_called = 0

@bot.command()
async def hi(ctx):
    # Compare the current time to when the command was last successfully
    # called.
    global last_called
    now = time.time()
    if now - last_called <= 90:
        await not_now(ctx)
    else:
        last_called = now
        await ctx.send('Hello')

@bot.command()
async def not_now(ctx):
    await ctx.send('Please wait a minute.')

bot.run(TOKEN)
```

Using global variables is not generally the best idea, but unfortunately subclassing `Bot` for tidier encapsulation of data into a single object is [quite clunky](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63403758/is-oop-possible-using-discord-py-without-cogs).