# Discord bot alive and handling messages, but NOT responding to commands

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I implemented this dicord bot as a Class `MyBot`, inheriting from `commands.Bot`. `run()` gets called from outside of the class definition, on the instance.

```python
from discord.ext import commands
from discord import Intents

class MyBot(commands.Bot):

    def __init__(self) -> None:
        intents = Intents.default()
        intents.message_content = True

        super().__init__(
            command_prefix='$', 
            intents=intents
            )


    @commands.command(name='hello')
    async def hello(self, ctx):
        await ctx.send('Hello!')

    async def on_ready(self):
        print(f'{self.user}<{self.user.id}> is now running')


    async def on_message(self, message):
        await self.process_commands(message)
        print(f'{self.user}<{self.user.id}> received a message')
```

**Now the bot is running!** `on_ready` triggers fine and every message I send gets handled by `on_message` - even the command messages! For some reason **commands don't get caught by** `hello` when I type "$hello" in the discord chat.

The line `await self.process_commands(message)` in the `on_message` handler was something I picked up in another thread, but it didn't solve my problem.

I also tried the decorater without `name='hello'`. I'm on Windows 10, **Python v3.11** and **discord.py v2.2.2**

-----------------EDIT------------------

Now what you can do apparently, is introduce a seperate class that defines the desired command behavior, and then register that class in `MyBot` as a `commands.Cog`:

```python
from discord.ext import commands
from discord import Intents

class CommandCog(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @commands.command()
    async def hello(self, ctx):
        await ctx.send('Hello!')

class MyBot(commands.Bot):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        intents = Intents.default()
        intents.message_content = True

        super().__init__(
            command_prefix='$', 
            intents=intents
            )

    async def on_ready(self):
        await self.add_cog(CommandCog(self))  # <--- register here
        print(f'{self.user}<{self.user.id}> is now running')


    async def on_message(self, message):
        await self.process_commands(message)
        print(f'{self.user}<{self.user.id}> received a message')
```

**Kudos to ChatGPT for this solution. Seems hacky af though. But it works!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be fixed by moving your command away from the class, and calling it like you normally would.

```
from discord.ext import commands
from discord import Intents

class MyBot(commands.Bot):

    def __init__(self) -> None:
        intents = Intents.default()
        intents.message_content = True

        super().__init__(
            command_prefix='$', 
            intents=intents
            )

    async def on_ready(self):
        print(f'{self.user}<{self.user.id}> is now running')

    async def on_message(self, message):
        await self.process_commands(message)
        print(f'{self.user}<{self.user.id}> received a message')

bot = MyBot()

@bot.command(name='hello')
async def hello(ctx):
    await ctx.send('Hello!')

bot.run(TOKEN)
```

Edit:
If you want to declare your commands within the bot class, you could try something like this:

```
class MyBot(commands.Bot):

    def __init__(self) -> None:
        intents = Intents.default()
        intents.message_content = True

        super().__init__(
            command_prefix='$', 
            intents=intents
            )
        
        @self.command(name='hello')
        async def custom_command(ctx):
            await ctx.send('Hello!')

    async def on_ready(self):
        print(f'{self.user}<{self.user.id}> is now running')

    async def on_message(self, message):
        await self.process_commands(message)
        print(f'{self.user}<{self.user.id}> received a message')

bot = MyBot()
bot.run(TOKEN)
```

Comment: That would be a solution, but I want it as part of my class definition. I tell you why: The class should define the behavior of every instance. It's nice to have the option, to define custom command behavior on an instance, but if I want to define a command behavior for every instance of that bot class, it doesn't seem like the right approach to me. You see the issue?

Comment: Yeah alright, another approach could be something like in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63403758/is-oop-possible-using-discord-py-without-cogs. I'll update my answer, just let me know if it's what you're wanting.